# Change route resource name for a specific action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm hoping this is a really simple thing that I'm just not seeing. I'm fairly new to rails so I imagine this is right under my nose.

My app has what you call `stacks` and I created a resource for it:

`resources :stacks, only: [:new, :create, :show]`

I want to change the route for the show action from `/stacks/:id` to `/stack/:id`

I had added this above the resource, but it wasn't working:

`get '/stacks/:id', to: 'stacks#show', as: 'stack'`

Thanks!

Edit: code

```
get '/stacks/:id', to: 'stacks#show', as: 'stack'
resources :stacks, only: [:new, :create, :show]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails pluralizes resource names by default for purposes of routing, database table names, etc., but you can override specific cases of this behavior.

Go to your Ruby on Rails application folder (we'll just call it '.app' for our purposes here). Open .app/config/initializers/inflections.rb in an editor and you'll see the following (Rails 4):

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Add new inflection rules using the following format. Inflections
# are locale specific, and you may define rules for as many different
# locales as you wish. All of these examples are active by default:
# ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
#   inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
#   inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
#   inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
#   inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )
# end

# These inflection rules are supported but not enabled by default:
# ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
#   inflect.acronym 'RESTful'
# end
```

Add an Inflector so that "stack" is the plural of "stack", like so:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'stack', 'stack'
end
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: This is great, but doesn't this change the entire resource? It'd be great if the `index` action could be `/stacks` and the `show` action could be `/stack/:id`

Comment: When you say you added get '/stacks/:id', to: 'stacks#show', as: 'stack'above the resource, where and how did you add it, and how are you using it on your stack_controller.rb?

Comment: `get '/stacks/:id', to: 'stacks#show', as: 'stack'
resources :stacks, only: [:new, :create, :show]`